# PrtScn Button in the IE not behaving as other browsers using java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I've been using the following javascript code that blocks Normal users (not professionals of course) from using print screen & Ctrl+A &  Ctrl+C on the browser.
it does work as expected on Firefox & Chrome but it sometimes works on IE and some other times it fails. Please review the code if you can a little help of maybe what's going wrong on IE. and why it fails?

```
function disableselect(e) {
    return false;
}
function reEnable() {
    return true;
}
document.onselectstart = new Function("return false");
if (window.sidebar) {
    document.onmousedown = disableselect;
    document.onclick = reEnable;
}
function copyToClipboard() {
  // Create a "hidden" input
  var aux = document.createElement("input");
  // Assign it the value of the specified element
  aux.setAttribute("value", "You can no longer give print-screen. This is part of the new system security measure");
  // Append it to the body
  document.body.appendChild(aux);
  // Highlight its content
  aux.select();
  // Copy the highlighted text
  document.execCommand("copy");
  // Remove it from the body
  document.body.removeChild(aux);
  alert("You can no longer give print-screen. This is part of the new system security measure.");
}
$(window).keyup(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 44){
    copyToClipboard();
  }
}); 
$(window).focus(function() {
  $("body").show();
}).blur(function() {
  $("body").hide();
});
```

Comment: for faster, better replies, please specify the version of IE that you are testing against

Comment: The IE v. I'm using is IE 11 but I would love it to work with as many versions as possible I understand that it's an annoying thing to do on a site but that's how the client wants to behave! so much appreciated @ControlAltDel for help

Comment: I've tried to make this code to work using some simulation code to trigger a fake key up so that it would load with window load, but I wasn't successful here's the code on js fiddle. Any Help will be appreciated https://jsfiddle.net/50e6yh87/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tested it and it works for me using Chrome, Firefox, IE11.

But, if someone use Inspect Element to disable CSS restriction, then he will disable it :)

Comment: if someone presses print screen on IE without using any key before he will be able to print screen without any problem :) there are many ways to break it really. it's just a symbolic code to restrict children in school from passing information to each other easily nothing more.